# NoReverseMatch как решить?

Tags: django

'blog' is not a registered namespace.
Что я делаю не так?
Вот код:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.main_page, name='main_page'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<index>[0-9]+)/$', views.page_post, name='post'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^registration/$', views.register, name='registration'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),

]

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Log In</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'blog:login'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_username">
                                Username:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_password">
                                Password:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_password" maxlength="30" name="password" type="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'blog:register' %}">Click here</a> to register.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

{% endblock %}

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

Comment: urls.py не показываете.

Comment: Добавил урлы смотрите

Comment: Просто `{% url 'login' %}`.

Comment: @SergeyGonostaev Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую, у тебя не видит приложение block, подключи в url проекта

```
urlpatterns = [
....
       url(r'^', include('block.urls', namespace='block')),
....
]
```